Apply a force to an object relative to direction of another
I'm making an fps game, and with that in mind, strafing is important. I am trying to make the player move relative to where they are looking in-game.
I have 3 Vector3s, moveDir, lookDir, & forceDir. moveDir is the vector of movement (i.e. pressing D (rightward) makes moveDir's Z set to 1, W (forward) sets the X value to 1, etc.). `lookDir` is the direction the player is looking, flattened to only care about y rotation. And forceDir is the vector force would be applied.
I have tried various methods of combining the move & look Dir to set forceDir (multiplying the move & look Dirs primarily), but that produced odd results.
A crudely drawn image of my desired vs actual player movements.

If I were holding W (forward) I would expect to move toward the direction the player is facing, holding A (leftward) I would expect to move perpendicularly left to the direction the player is facing. instead it only applies these forces relative to world space, or even more strangely, when I am looking down the X or Z planes.
Code block for context: (it is run every frame)
private void MovePlayer()
{
    //above I have it so inputs are handled (fore & backwards motion is handled in walkY, strafing in walkX)
    walkX = Mathf.Clamp(walkX, -1.42f, 1.42f); walkY = Mathf.Clamp(walkY, -1.42f, 1.42f);
    walkDir = new Vector3(walkY, 0, walkX);
    walkX *= 0.7f; walkY *= 0.7f;
    walkX = (walkX >= 0.001f || walkX <= 0.001f ? 0 : walkX);
    walkY = (walkY >= 0.001f || walkY <= 0.001f ? 0 : walkY);

    //"flattening" the look direction, so it only cares about Y rotation
    Vector3 lookDir = Vector3.Scale(mainCamera.transform.forward, new Vector3(0, 1, 0));

    //Vector3.zero until I can find out how to properly do what I want
    Vector3 forceDir = Vector3.zero;

    //apply the force
    playerRB.AddForce(forceDir * walkSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}


well looking at your code you have the knowledge, the question is then suggestive you havent understood what you did...

First of all instead of clamping weirdly on +- 1.42 (I assume you mean √2 here) you rather should clamp the entire input vector using Vector3.ClampMagnitude
var input = new Vector3(walkY, 0, walkX);
// This ensures that even when moving diagonal the input is never bigger than 1 in total
input = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(input, 1f);

walkDir = input;

// not sure why this magic factor
input *= 0.7f; 

Then next your conditions like
walkX >= 0.001f || walkX <= 0.001f

will always be true - I think you forgot to add some - symbols and use && instead of || as in
input.x = input.x >= -0.001f && input.x <= 0.001f ? 0 : input.x;

or simply use Mathf.Abs to make it a bit easier to read
input.x = Mathf.Abs(input.x) <= 0.001f ? 0f : input.x;


and then coming to your actually question: Instead of using camera.transform.forward which is a vector you could rather simply use the camera.transform.rotation in order to rotate your entire input vector and rather flatten it afterwards:
// input is now aligned with the camera rotation so 
// input.x points in camera.transform.right direction
// input.z points in camera.transform.forward direction
var forceDir = camera.transform.rotation * input;

// erases the Y and normalizes so now you have a vector in the global XZ plane
forceDir.y = 0;
// optional - it could e.g. be desired that if looking straight down the forward is shrinking
forceDir.Normalize();

So this should now add your forces in the correct directions
playerRB.AddForce(forceDir * walkSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);


Unity has a sort of movement fucntion that can be used liked this:
float moveX = Input.getAxisRaw("Horizontal"); //A and D
float moveZ = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"); //W and S
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveX, 0, moveY) * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
transform.Translate(movement);

this then moves the player based on the way that you are looking, moving with added force is not what I would recommend
